# Creating a simple animation that plays while key is pressed

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I would like to do the following and I am wondering what the most efficient approach is:

While a particular key is pressed, I want to cycle through a set of jpegs at a rate that I can specify from one jpeg to the next, and then have the final image maintained on the screen indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow. It is usually customary to provide some examples of what you have attempted. Next time, try something first. We are a lot more helpful when we see some code!

This should get you started. It will simply `console.log` while the `enter/return` key is held down. Once it is released, it makes one more `console.log` and rebinds the event for the next time the `enter/return` key is held down.

[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccW7Q/)

```
(function(){
  var intervalId;

  // your animations should go here
  var someFunc = function(){
    console.log("executing");
  }

  var keyDownFn = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){ // 13 is enter/return
      $(window).unbind('keydown.animation');
      $(window).bind('keyup.animation', keyUpFn);
      intervalId = setInterval(someFunc, 500);
    }
  }

  var keyUpFn = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){ // 13 is enter/return
      console.log("stopping");
      $(window).unbind('keyup.animation');
      $(window).bind('keydown.animation', keyDownFn);
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    } 
  }

  // this line fires the whole thing off
  $(window).bind('keydown.animation', keyDownFn);

})();​
```